# Reference for a result in Abelian Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, abelian-groups, unimodular-matrices

I'm looking for a reference of the following result:

*Suppose $G$ is a non trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ of the form $H \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ where $H$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $rank(G)= l$ and $l + m = n$. Then there exist $\tau_1, \dots, \tau_l$, $\pi_1, \dots, \pi_m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $G$ is generated by $\tau_1, \dots, \tau_l$ and $$M = [\tau_1, \dots, \tau_l, \pi_1, \dots, \pi_m] \in SL(n, \mathbb{Z}).$$*

In the article I'm reading (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1991v068n01ABEH001371) this is mentioned as a result from the theory of abelian groups and the author refers to Bourbaki algebra book for more details. I have not been able to find the result there so I am not sure if this is the precise statement.

Additionally, I would like to know if there is any explicit relation between $G$ and $M$. For example, if $G$ admits a basis with vectors of norm less than some positive constant $A$ what can we say of the matrix $M$? Is there a constant $c$ depending only on $n$ such that $\| M\| < cA$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't open the article. Is the link still working?

Comment: Without an additional assumption, like $G$ being pure in $\mathbb Z^n$, this need not be true. The "smallest" counterexample would be $n=l=1$ (so $m=0$) and $G$ consisting of just the even integers. Then $M$ will be the $1\times1$ matrix whose single entry is $2$, and that's not in $SL(1,\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @withoutfeather The link works for me. The article is "The mechanism of resonance tori of Hamiltonian systems" by D. Treshchev.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You are right. The subgroups appearing in the article are hyperplanes of $\mathbb{R}^n$ intersected with $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and those are indeed pure. I will modify the statement.

Comment: @withoutfeather I get Service Unavailable
The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.